# Mixing Java POJOs & GWT Overlay types

Tags: gwt, overlay, pojo

In my app I use JsArray extensively to store my overlay types. I use java.util.List to store my client-side Java POJOs.

For performance reasons and to unify the way I access my model I planned to eliminate the Lists and use only JSO wrappers. Given a wrapper around a native array that can store any Java Object:

```
 public class JsArrayObject<T> extends JavaScriptObject {

        protected JsArrayObject() {}

        public final native T get(int index) /*-{
            return this[index];
        }-*/;

        public final native void push(T value) /*-{
            this[this.length] = value;
        }-*/;
    }
```

Is it safe to store Java Objects this way? The doc says that when you pass a Java Object into JavaScript the result is "an opaque value accessible through special syntax". This sounds confussing to me. For instance if I push an Integer and try to get it an exception will be thrown because something different than an Object was found (at least in dev mode). The same happens with the rest of Java primitive Wrappers. Apart from the problems with Java primitive Wrappers, are there other concerns to be aware?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which doc are you referring to? The one on [this page](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit-doc-1-5/wiki/DevGuideMarshaling)?

They're talking in terms of passing Java objects into JavaScript with the intent of having JavaScript code use the methods or fields in the object. It is possible to do that, but the syntax you have to use on the JavaScript side is a bit awkward. If you've done any JSNI, you've seen it.

If you don't intend to access the Java objects from the JavaScript side you can ignore the business about the special syntax. So yes, it is safe. I'd be interested to know if it actually turns out to help performance.

Comment: Thanks. I now understand what they meant with "an opaque value accessible through special syntax". My intention is to use JavaScriptObjects to store Java POJOs but I do not need to invoke Java methods from Javascript. My only concern is whether the compiler will mess up with this structure.

Comment: The compiler isn't going to mess anything up. When the JavaScript interpreter is running the code that the GWT compiler generated, everything is either a JavaScript primitive or a JavaScript object. Some of those JavaScript objects represent Java objects. The Java and JavaScipt object models are sufficiently different that the Java objects look weird from the JavaScript side, but if that was a problem, GWT wouldn't work at all.

Comment: came here to thank you for your expedient and most useful answer [Embrace Jargon](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15187/whats-the-difference-between-client-and-customer/26403#26403) since I cannot either respond or upvote there having life ban there